# Mongoose can't find recent saved

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to save the IP address of the client who connects to my script.

However, while I am not getting any errors, when I check the collection it is empty.

index.js (main app)

```
const Listeners = require('mongoose').model('listeners');

const userData = {"ipaddress":ip}

const Listener = new Listeners(userData);

Listener.save(function (err, userData) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
});
```

Mongoose index.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports.connect = (uri) => {
  mongoose.connect(uri, {useCreateIndex: true, useFindAndModify: false , useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
  // plug in the promise library:
  mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

  mongoose.connection.on('open',function() {
    console.log('Mongoose connected. what did you think');
    });

  mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error(`Mongoose connection error: ${err}`);
    process.exit(1);
  });

  // load models
  require('./listener');

};
```

My listener file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
// define the User model schema
const ListenerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ipaddress: {
      type: String,
     // index: { unique: true }
    },
    station: String,
    start_time:{
     type: Date
    },
    end_time:{
        type: Date
    }
  }, { collection: 'listeners'});


  /**
 * The pre-save hook method.
 */
ListenerSchema.pre('save', function saveHook(next) {
    const Listener = this;
  console.log(this)
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('listeners', ListenerSchema);
```

when I run it I get `{ _id: 5e2bf98549ae2d5d6da52475, ipaddress: '127.0.0.1' }`

However when I open the mongodb collection I see nothing.

There seems to not be an error, but there must be?

Answer (score 0):

**The only one reason** why you can't save your data into your `collection` it's because this code in your `listener` file.

‍ **Try to comment** this code below :

```
  /**
 * The pre-save hook method.
 */
ListenerSchema.pre('save', function saveHook(next) {
    const Listener = this;
  console.log(this)
});
```

‍ or, **the second option** is add `next` function in there. So, your code will looks like this code below :

```js
  /**
 * The pre-save hook method.
 */
ListenerSchema.pre('save', function saveHook(next) {
    const Listener = this;
    console.log(this);
    // add next function below
    next();
});
```

And now, **you can try again** and I'm sure, you can see the collection in your mongodb.

I hope it's can help you .